# MacOS Mojave: App launches from Terminal but not from Finder

Tags: mac, python

Thanks in advance for any help.

I downloaded a Python app called Manuskript, extracted the tarball and tried to make an App from it. Created the directory structure (Manuskript.app, Contents, MacOS, Resources) and copied the whole application tree inside 'Resources', wrote an Info.plist file, and a shell script inside 'MacOS' to launch the application. Used xattr to clear all the extended attributes from every file, and chmoded 755 the shell script.

The App shows in Finder with the correct icon, but it doesn't launch, either with Ctrl-RightClick-Open or a double LeftClick. If I launch it from Terminal, with 'open -a Manuskript.app', it starts and works correctly.

I'd appreciate any suggestions for further things to try.

Regards,

Sergio Reyes-Peniche

Comment: Could you include a picture of the app running?  Just to show us that it is a Mac "native" (?) app, and not a Terminal-based script or executable.  I've used Platypus a LOT to make Mac-native apps out of scripts, so maybe give that a try if this is a script or executable.

Comment: As I stated in the OP, it is not a 'native' app but a Python one, PyQt5 in particular. I have the correct directory structure and it runs fine from the command line with 'open -a Manuskript.app' displaying the correct app name and icon in the Dock, but it cannot be launched from the Finder. I will research this Platypus option you mention. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch it from Finder, you can create an alias of manuskript,  copy or move it to /Applications, change the icon, and when launched you can select the "Keep in Dock" option.

Answer (score -1):

From Recovery (command R) when you boot up— from the menu Reinstall the macOS on top of your existing macOS.  This is your best option for re-gaining your Finder.

This will preserve all your user data/files.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718

Comment: I'll keep this in mind as a last resort. I don't think Finder is damaged somehow, as every other app launches normally.